# CouchDB & E4X for documents containing XML

Tags: xml, couchdb, e4x

I have a CouchDB database (v1.2.0) with documents like:

```
{
   "_id": "pages/1",
   "_rev": "15-56ad5a5e879206edb04a7a62105dd25d",
   "content": "<html lang=\"en\"><head><title>Page Title</title></head></html>"
}
```

According to [this article](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2008/03/couchdb-xml-and-e4x) I should simply write a view like this one:

```
// by_lang
function(doc) {
    var html = new XML(doc.content);
    emit(html.@lang, {title: html.head.title.text()});
}
```

, to get data from the XML.

Unfortunately that doesn't work. At first I though that the CouchDB binaries I've downloaded don't include SpiderMonkey which includes E4X, but that is not the case. If I add a `log(html);` statement I can see the XML been parsed correctly (@ the Erlang window).

What the Erlang window states that is wrong with my code is this:

```
Log :: function raised exception (new TypeError("String.prototype.toJSON called on incompatible XML", "../share/couchdb/server/main.js", 1138)) with doc._id pages/1
```

I opened the `main.js` file and the code that breaks is the following:

```
// moving this away from global so we can move to json2.js later
toJSON : function (val) {
    return JSON.stringify(val);
},
```

Googling for that error brought me to [this page](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-dev/200912.mbox/%3Ce282921e0912191707u7a09e8eco2d8a54aec3119471@mail.gmail.com%3E) which mentions json2.js (which is also mentioned in the remark in the code above.

Any ideas how to solve this? Is there any chance that this is a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that `toJSON` couldn't convert whatever the `html.@lang` object is (it's not a plain string until you call `.toString()`

So, change your `emit` to include `toString()` calls (note that I also changed the `.text()` call to a `.toString()` call:

```
emit(html.@lang.toString(), {title: html.head.title.toString()});
```

Comment: `emit(html.@lang.toString(), {title: html.head.title.text().toString()});` did the trick! Omitting the `.text()` part also produces the same result. Thanx!